# Cannot create documentdb database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Creating a new Document database with shared provision throughput at 400 through Azure Portal fails with "The offer should have valid throughput values between 50000 and 1000000 inclusive in increments of 10000." in West Europe region.

What am I missing? :-)

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest opening a support ticket - nothing that can be solved here, and this is not normal behavior (and this is an Azure support issue, not a programming issue). But to be thorough: I just created a 400-RU shared database in W Europe to double-check that there's nothing odd in that region. Worked fine.

Comment: Alternatively, try deploying a new Cosmos DB account, to see if the problem was specific to the original account you created. But I'm sure the support team will be interested in hearing from you, including all of your details (subscription id, deployment id, etc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon AzureSupport at Twitter asked me to create it here, and I think they created an internal ticket for further investigation.
(I'm not sure how this support thing is working)

Comment: Right, so... for programming questions, Azure Support would be correct. But this is a service-level (or subscription-level) issue, so unfortunately it doesn't go here.

Comment: Got it. maybe someone working on that product could align text and error message like "hey, your subscription/service level do not have permission to create a throughput at 400" :-) but thank you @DavidMakogon they just reached out to me.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to support, this was a bug fixed last week but still cached in my browser.

Clearing cache fixed it.